# I want to make input range slider with react+ typescript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I was made code and slider by this code

```
import { mainModule } from 'process';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const DragScaleBar = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    const changeWidth = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        setValue(parseInt(event.target.value));
    };
    const MIN = 0;
    const MAX = 10;

    const DeadlineStyle = styled.h1`
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 25em;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    `;
    const DragStyle = styled.input`
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background: #f5f6fa;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 2em;
        margin-left: 18em;
        width: 20em;
        height: 1em;
        border-radius: 1em;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0.75px black;

        &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 2px solid white;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            opacity: 0.8;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: gray;
        }
    `;

    return (
        <>
            <DeadlineStyle>마감일 + {value} Day</DeadlineStyle>
            <div>
                <DragStyle
                    type="range"
                    min={MIN}
                    max={MAX}
                    value={value}
                    step="1"
                    onChange={changeWidth}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default DragScaleBar;

and here is picture
```

slider can change value to click in slider area.
but when I use onchange event, dragEvent is not working

I tried onMouseUp replace for onChange, but I don't know how can I use that
with typescript.

is anyone else solved problem like my code before??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting your styled components inside of your "real" component is causing them to re-render each time you update the value which causes the bug you are describing.

Extracting all the things which do not need to be re-rendered outside of your `DragScaleBar` will fix your issue.

Have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-joji-f9u0xw?file=/src/DragScaleBar.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const DeadlineStyle = styled.h1`
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
`;
const DragStyle = styled.input`
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #f5f6fa;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 0em;
  width: 20em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0.75px black;

  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 2px solid white;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: gray;
  }
`;

const MIN = 0;
const MAX = 10;

const DragScaleBar = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const changeWidth = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(parseInt(event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DeadlineStyle>마감일 + {value} Day</DeadlineStyle>
      <div>
        <DragStyle
          type="range"
          min={MIN}
          max={MAX}
          value={value}
          step="1"
          onChange={changeWidth}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default DragScaleBar;
```

ps, you do not need to do `event.preventDefault()` in your `changeWidth` method :)

Comment: thanks for help!!!! I wish I can analyze the code like you...someday

Comment: no worries. And you will :)